# Creating a color palette, <img> or <div> or <canvas>?

Tags: html, semantics

I'm currently working on an color-picker component using HTML, CSS and Javascript, one major question is how I should implement a color palette like this one:

[image]

Ignoring browser compatibility issues introduced by IE8 or earlier, I have 3 methods to implement this:

1. The `<img>` way:

   This is simple and is used by many color-picker components for years, we simply include an image exactly the same as the above one using `<img src="palette.png" />`.

   The problem is `<img>` would introduce extra network roundtrip, although we can prevent it using dataURI, but an image data is a little **too large** for me.
2. The `<div>` way:

   In this way we should use 2 `<div>` elements, one of them provides a left-to-right linear gradient and the other provides a top-to-bottom alpha gradient, the style should be:

   ```
   <style>
       #map {
           width: 400px; 
           height: 400px;
           background: -webkit-gradient(
               linear, left top, right top, 
               color-stop(0%,#ff0000), 
               color-stop(16.67%,#ffff00), 
               color-stop(33.33%,#00ff00),
               color-stop(50%,#00ffff), 
               color-stop(66.67%,#0000ff),
               color-stop(83.33%,#ff00ff), 
               color-stop(100%,#ff0000)
           );
       }
       #overlay {
           width: 400px;
           height: 400px;
           background: -webkit-gradient(
               linear, left top, left bottom, 
               from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), 
               to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1))
           );
       }
   </style>

   <div id="palette"><div id="overlay"></div></div>
   ```

   It works perfectly, but the problem is, this method introduces 2 elements for styling only, the 2 `<div>` elements don't have any semantic meanings and don't act as a generic container or block, this is **a violation to semantic HTML**.
3. The `<canvas>` way:

   `<canvas>` provides very flexible graphic API to implement such a color palette, I use these code to draw it:

   ```
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

   var palette = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 360, 0);
   palette.addColorStop(0 / 6, '#ff0000');
   palette.addColorStop(1 / 6, '#ffff00');
   palette.addColorStop(2 / 6, '#00ff00');
   palette.addColorStop(3 / 6, '#00ffff');
   palette.addColorStop(4 / 6, '#0000ff');
   palette.addColorStop(5 / 6, '#ff00ff');
   palette.addColorStop(6 / 6, '#ff0000');
   context.fillStyle = palette;
   context.fillRect(0, 0, 360, 360);

   var overlay = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 360);
   overlay.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
   overlay.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)');
   context.fillStyle = overlay;
   context.fillRect(0, 0, 360, 360);
   ```

   It works as well as the above 2 approaches, but I wonder whether I should use canvas to draw such a static image, shouldn't canvas be used in more dynamic and complex enviroment?

So which way should I go to implement a simple color palette, or is there a better approach?

Comment: Using a couple of `<div>`s has no bearing on whether or not your HTML is semantic. Aren't buzzwords fun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to use an image, but don't want the extra request, you could use a [data URI](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/):

```
<img width="184" height="184" title="" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U6bpf/)

Comment: It seems not as large as I thought, the size is acceptable in a 180x180 dimension, I would give it a try

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the color palette?

Is it just to display? Then perhaps an image would serve best as it can be cached and compressed.

Do you plan to use the palette to select a color? Then I would go with canvas as it is very easy to find a pixel's color that way.

Comment: This palette is a part of my color-picker component, so I should register mouse events on this palette and calculate color using an offset x/y.

Answer (score 0):

An extra image request *really* isn't that bad; and like bookcasey [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798242/719312), you could always embed it.

I'd go with the `<canvas>` though. There's nothing particularly wrong with using `<div>`s, but if a user is browsing with CSS off it won't work. (And yes, some of us do browse with CSS off)

The `<canvas>` not only works with CSS off, it's more semantic, whereas the `<divs>` seem pointless to a screenreader or search engine.

Also, the `<canvas>` is going to allow you *much* more flexibility in the long run, what with the JS apis and such.

For example, with canvas you could implement multiple ways to pick a color (using any of several [color models](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Hsl-hsv_models.svg) to select a color.

With `<div>`s or images, this extra functionality would quickly clog either the DOM or your server with HTTP requests, but with Canvas, you have a lot more flexibility with minimal needed resources